# XML Serialization in c# d1p1 and xmlns

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

When i create a new xml file, in xml's element there are things like d1p1 and xmlns and i dont want it. 
what should I do?
this mine xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f_section d1p1:id="" xmlns:d1p1="171210235434">
     <tar>01/01/2017</tar>
</f_section>
```

what I want to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f_section id="171210235434">
     <tar>01/01/2017</tar>
</f_section>
```

Comment: How are you serializing your class? Maybe you can add that code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide serializer code, try something like that to remove namespaces;

```
var xmlNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer();
xmlNamespace.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
//Actions
serializer.Serialize(stream, object, xmlNamespace);
```